# Windows 8 CredentialPicker - Advice for a Win8 beginner

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I've been doing .NET console, .NET Webforms, and light WPF work before, but this is my first foray into Windows 8 Metro development.

I'm developing an app that's dependent on a web service that requires an authentication token. The app is kind of useless without this token; they only need to provide this token and not a username or password. The token can be revoked by the service provider in the event the app needs to be de-authorized.

Since the token is basically required for any app functionality; it needs to be global, it needs to persist for the lifetime of the app; it would be great if the app remembered the credential in a secure way after the app terminates to be loaded on the next run. I tried sticking a CredentialPicker in the App.xaml.cs file, however I guess the credentialpicker needs to be on an actual page? What's the best way to make this global, and spawn the credentialpicker whenever the model class detects there's no credentials for whatever reason?

My logic I thought would be:

```
Boot App
Load App Start Page
Check Disk for Credential Hash
If Hash Not Exist, Launch CredentialPicker
    Validate Credential/Key 
    If Credential/Key not valid, 
        Relaunch CredentialPicker
    Else
        Store Credentials To Disk
Else
    Use Existing Credentials; Proceed

Store Credentials In PasswordVault for use during this app lifecycle
```

Apologize for the verbosity; I just want to know best practices using an application-wide set of credentials in Win8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're authenticating with a web service, you want to use the Web Authentication Broker instead (Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker, also see the sample on http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122). The collection of credentials stays in the broker, and you get the server response back that typically contains the key you need for subsequent calls.

Using the credential picker for this purpose isn't really what you want, as that UI is primarily intended for enterprise scenarios, and still requires that you manage the credentials directly in the app. The Web Auth Broker was designed so the credentials always exists on the service and all you get back is the key. There is also a topic in the docs [Web authentication broker for online providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj856911.aspx) on creating a login page that will work great inside the broker.

Note that you can use the password vault for the key--just give it some dummy username in the credential object.

Comment: I see. I am integrating with Campfire and didn't know they had OAuth capabilities. Hopefully that should make things easier. Previously I was using the 'API key' method.
https://github.com/37signals/api/blob/master/sections/authentication.md
So I suppose I use the WebAuthenticationBroker, check the responsedata for the token, and use that token for my subsequent web requests. Will have to dig more into the 37 Signals docs.